# Android. SetText doesn't change the text for Button

Tags: android, kotlin

I have custom view - custom keyboard.
Each button is `MaterialButton`.
I need to implement `shift` button to change letters case, so I've done it this way

```
private fun onCaseChanged() {
    buttons.forEach { button ->
        (button as? TextView)?.let {
            val text = it.text.toString()
            it.text = if (isUpperCase)
                text.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())
            else
                text.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
        }
    }
}
```

All is working correct except UI - text on buttons doesn't change.
When I change buttons to `TextView`s - all works fine. But not with any type of `Button`.
So for now it seems like only way for me.

Bu I'm still curious - if there's another way to fix this problem with leaving `MaterialButton`s

Comment: The problem is the keys stay in lower case and don't ever become upper case?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat yes. They work correctly, print letters in needed case, but letters on the buttons stay unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:textAllCaps="false"` in the Button declaration in your XML files.
If that successfully works, I suggest changing the default button style in your theme so that it defaults to false if that's what you need.

Example

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:textAllCaps="false"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        />
```

Comment: I don't know what to say. It seems to be such a dumb mistake... How could I miss that. Thanks a lot!